# MAC Keychain tool integration with OpenSSL

Tags: macos, ssl, openssl, keychain, openssl-engine

We already have visited the link at [OpenSSL and Apple Keychain integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008295/openssl-keychain-integration/15341662), but didn't found anything about engine. Also the question asked in above link is too old.

Is there any implementation of such type of engine till now or not?

Comment: OS X is developmental backwater. Even Mozilla and NSS lacks Apple keychain integration. As far as I know, the only browser that integrates well is Safari. (But browsers are broken anyways... Protected Storage is not standardized. Its completely lacking, so all sensitive information could show up in the filesystem with the only protection being browser's origin fences).